# AWS Lambda function triggered without event (ghost trigger)

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda function which is configured to be triggered by Kafka topic. (self-managed). After I process around 600-700 requests, I disabled the trigger.

However, lambda function is still being triggered. Kafka trigger is disabled, and it doesn't get any messages.

I know this is synchronous trigger. However just to be sure, I set Asynchronous invocation settings as

```
Maximum age of event: 0h 1min 0sec
Retry attempts: 0
```

It is still being triggered, and each execution gives timeout error while doing API call. (of course, this might not related to my question)

Is there some kind of queue in which lambda function polls some requests itself?
Do you have any idea?

Comment: Kafka triggers are delivered via SQS so yes, there is a queue. It's possible that not everything was consumed after disabling the Kafka trigger. Does it eventually stop after a short period of time?  You mention an error in the call - are you deleting the messages from the queue once you consume them?  Or do they come back after the visibility timeout?

Comment: Thanks for comment. How can see that SQS which is associated with my lambda function. Is it possible to see pending messages and somehow clean them?